# error: class, interface, or enum expected when compiling

Tags: java, class, interface, enums

```
public void buildButtonPanel()
  {

     buttonPanel = new JPanel();

     calcButton = new JButton("Calculate Charges");
     exitButton = new JButton("Exit");


     calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
     exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());


     buttonPanel.add(calcButton);
     buttonPanel.add(exitButton);



        private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
        {

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)


              total = routine.getRoutineCost() +
                      nonRoutine.getNonRoutineCost();

              DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total: $" + dollar.format(total));

         }

        private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
        {            

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)


              System.exit(0);
         }
```

error:class, interface, or enum expected

on each line same error.

I'm assuming it's a brace error but I've redone my braces 3 times and I'm still getting this same error on this same section.

Comment: There is no closing brace at the end of the whole buildButtonPanel class.  Where is the error appearing?

Comment: It starts at  public void buildButtonPanel. if it helps, the indicator for the error is under the v in void for the first line and then continues at calcButton = new JButton("Calculate Charges");

Comment: Is there anything else in the file that contains this class? It's possible that the issue is coming from something before the class.  And did you see that I had said you didn't have a closing brace at the end of the class?

Comment: yes I did and I added it and am still receiving the error. There is no other place that that class is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buildButtonPanel needs to have a closing brace before the classes.

It needs to go here because you cannot have classes inside of methods.

```
  buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
}
```

Is all of the code you've shown us wrapped in a class? buildButtonPanel is a method and must be within a class.

Your actionPerformed methods also do not have braces.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  // Your code goes here
}
```